# Custom Layout Manager using predefined and developer-defined child view(s)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-custom-view, viewgroup

**Revised Question**

When one looks online in tutorials, or by Google IO presentations, there are always just 2 kinds of UI customizations that one can do (but there are [several implementations of doing each type](http://lucasr.org/2014/05/12/custom-layouts-on-android/)). These customizations are:

1. Creating a custom view that is a composite of existing views, or your own
2. Creating a custom layout that is your own

However, what if I wanted to create a hybrid of these two? Specifically a Custom View that allow child views to be laid out how I define? There is nothing that I have found online (no tutorials, no videos) or even anything saying if this is even feasible.

### Idea

[image]

Here is the `Contacts App` that has something very similar to what I want to do. You notice that every list item has a very similar layout. Nothing special here. I can create `composite custom view` with `styleables` to set the primary and secondary text, and the main and action icons.

However, my secret sauce comes with the idea of changing the primary text (the blacked-out region) to some other view in XML! This view could be a `TextView`, `RatingBar`, `ProgressBar`, `VideoView`, `SurfaceView`, etc...

## Examples

### TextView

Here is an example of using my custom view that takes in a `developer-defined` `TextView`.

[image]

```
<com.example.customview.BaseViewLayout 
    ...
    custom:imageMainIcon="..."
    custom:imageActionIcon="..."
    custom:secondaryText="Home">

    <TextView
        ...
        android:text="User-defined TextView"
        ... />

</com.example.customview.BaseViewLayout>
```

### VideoView

Here is an example of using my same custom view that takes in a `developer-defined` `VideoView`.

[image]

```
<com.example.customview.BaseViewLayout 
    ...
    custom:imageMainIcon="..."
    custom:imageActionIcon="..."
    custom:secondaryText="Home">

    <VideoView
        ... />

</com.example.customview.BaseViewLayout>
```

### Code

### BaseCustomLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/detail_list_item"
    android:layout_width="450dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_not_available_white"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="72dp"

        android:layout_marginRight="72dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="72dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


        <ViewStub
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/view_stub_main_view"
            android:inflatedId="@+id/inflated_main_view" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="16dp"
                android:text="Item Type"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="  ·  "/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="16dp"

                android:text="Extra"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_not_available_white"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**So, how does a person go about developing a custom view like this?**

Comment: Hi, I can only think of doing it programatically. after extending the framelayout, you should also programatically add the customization in that class as long as it retains property of being a layout, a parent.

Comment: I just read about ViewStub and looking to see if that is possible. Looks kind of promising.

Comment: Down vote? Why? I have not found any resources on this type of problem. It is either all predefined views or all user-defined child views

Comment: ViewStub? I wanna check it out, oops it's not me who downvoted