# Creating Custom Views that accept other layouts in xml attributes

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-custom-view

I have an [open question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419534/custom-layout-manager-using-predefined-and-developer-defined-child-views) on here that I am trying to solve, and I might have found a possible solution that is less error-prone; however, I don't know how to code up the solution.

The solution would be very similar to how `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView` handles the header view in XML!! The only problem is that I have tried to search for the source code for `NavigationView`, but I cannot seem to find it. I can find other Android Source code easily - except for the newer Design Library.

If I can find the Source code from Google, then I can implement something similar.

### Code

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"  />
```

See that last line? I want to be able to do something like that for my own customView to insert another view inside it.

**So my question is:**

- Where is the source code for the Design Library's NavigationView?

  OR
- Is there another custom view that allows you to insert layouts inside of it that has code posted online?

  OR
- If there is nothing online, then how would a person go about doing that? It is possible. The NavigationView does it.

Comment: you could have a custom attribute, and parte it in the constructor of your custom view

Comment: Yes, I know it will be a custom attribute. But I don't know what to do once it is passed into the constructor with attributes

Comment: Instead of searching for custom views, search for custom viewgroup. From top of my head, there is a fab-toolbar library, It accepts multiple views and arrange them in linear layout.

Comment: You just have to inflate the view with that id

Comment: OK, glad it sounds very simple. I will go ahead with my idea that I have in my other question, and do what you suggest as I now know what I want is actually feasible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an exmaple how you might do it:
In your `resources.xml`:

```
<declare-styleable name="MyCustomView">
   <attr name="child_view" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

In your `MyCustomView.java`:

```
public class MyCustomView extends ViewGroup {

    public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyCustomView, 0, 0);

        int childView = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyCustomView_child_view, R.layout.default_child_view);
        a.recycle();

        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(childView, this, true);
    }
}
```

In your layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:custom_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

<your.package.MyCustomView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        custom_view:child_view="@layout/some_layout" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does this have to extend ViewGroup because I have another layout inside of it?

Comment: @Christopher if you want to inflate directly to the view - yes, it has to be subclass (though, not necessarily direct) of `ViewGroup`.

Comment: it appears that it has to be from ViewGroup. The inflate's second parameter does not work. So then that means I have to override OnLayout

Comment: It can be inderect subclass of `ViewGroup` - for example, you could extend `LinearLayout` as well.

Comment: got it, but if you check my linked question, you will see my XML file. Is that correct for inflating the view. Right now I have a ViewStub where I want this view to go

Comment: @Christopher wait, you want to be able to add views as children to your `CustomView`?

Comment: I am coding your solution and I don't think it does what I want. But I think it is kind of close. I don't want to inflate to the child view like you are doing I believe??

Comment: That was my original idea, but the linked way does not have to be done. I think the idea in this question is adequate to provide an xml attribute that has the right layout